# chai testing: array to include type of objects

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I'm currently testing a Node.js/Typescript app.

My function should return an array of objects.

Those objects should be of type:

```
type myType = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  level: number;
  categorie: string;
  name: string;
};
```

The following code doesn't work

```
const ach: any = await achievementsServiceFunctions.getAchievementsDeblocked(idAdmin);
expect(ach)
  .to.be.an('array')
  .that.contains('myType');
```

How do I check that my array contains the given type only? (didn't find this info on chai doc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chai doesn't provide a direct way to test all elements of an array for their type. So assuming that all the elements of the array are of the same type, I'd first test that the target is indeed an array and then iterate over its contents to test their type, as in:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect

// create a new type 
class MyType extends Object {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
// Note that this should be consistent with 
// TypeScript's 'type' directive)

// create some testable data
const ary = [
  new MyType,
  'this will FAIL',
  new MyType
]

// first, test for array type
expect(ary).to.be.an('array')

// then, iterate over the array contents and test each for type
ary.forEach((elt, index) => {
    expect(
      elt instanceof MyType, 
      `ary[${index}] is not a MyType`
    ).to.be.true
})
```

Which will output:

```
/.../node_modules/chai/lib/chai/assertion.js:141
  throw new AssertionError(msg, {
  ^
AssertionError: ary[1] is not a MyType: expected false to be true
  at ary.forEach (.../testElementTypes.js:12:38)
  at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at Object.<anonymous> (.../testElementTypes.js:11:5)
  at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

If the array contents are not homogeneous, you'd need to test each element for its type separately.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [chai-json-pattern](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-pattern/) plugins as well.

> Chai JSON pattern allows you to create blueprints for JavaScript objects to ensure validation of key information. It enables you to use JSON syntax extends with easy to use validators.

Besides, Since the `chai-json-pattern` plugin currently does not support TypeScript, we need to extend the method type of `chai.Assertion`.

I use the `faker` package to generate random test data conforming to `myType`.

E.g.

```
import faker from 'faker';
import chai, { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiJsonPattern from 'chai-json-pattern';
chai.use(chaiJsonPattern);

declare global {
  export namespace Chai {
    interface Assertion {
      matchPattern(pattern: string): void;
    }
  }
}

type myType = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  level: number;
  categorie: string;
  name: string;
};

describe('49047322', () => {
  it('should pass if the data has correct types', () => {
    const ach: myType[] = [
      {
        title: faker.name.title(),
        description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
        level: faker.random.number(),
        categorie: faker.lorem.word(),
        name: faker.name.findName(),
      },
      {
        title: faker.name.title(),
        description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
        level: faker.random.number(),
        categorie: faker.lorem.word(),
        name: faker.name.findName(),
      },
    ];
    expect(ach).to.matchPattern(`
      [
       {
        "title": String,
        "description":String,
        "level": Number,
        "categorie": String,
        "name": String
       }
      ]
    `);
  });

  it('should fail if the data has incorrect types', () => {
    const ach: myType[] = [
      {
        title: 1 as any,  // Simulate wrong type of data
        description: faker.lorem.sentence(),
        level: faker.random.number(),
        categorie: faker.lorem.word(),
        name: faker.name.findName(),
      },
    ];
    expect(ach).to.matchPattern(`
      [
       {
        "title": String,
        "description":String,
        "level": Number,
        "categorie": String,
        "name": String
       }
      ]
    `);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  49047322
    ✓ should pass if the data has correct types
    1) should fail if the data has incorrect types


  1 passing (27ms)
  1 failing

  1) 49047322
       should fail if the data has incorrect types:

      AssertionError: expected [ Array(1) ] to be like [ Array(1) ]
      + expected - actual

           "categorie": "nisi"
           "description": "Quae aut sint et earum quae."
           "level": 69341
           "name": "Mozell Green MD"
      -    "title": 1
      +    "title": "String"
         }
       ]
      
      at Context.it (src/stackoverflow/49047322/main.test.ts:63:20)
```