# Chai test Typescript type

Tags: typescript, chai

I'm using `node.js` with `mocha / chai / chai-http`.

I'd like to test my web service who returns an array of movies but I don't know how can I do that with `chai`. My movie type looks like :

```
type Movie = {
  id: number;
  year: number;
  rent_number: number;
  title: string;
  author: string
  editor: string;
}
```

So my web service `/movies` returns `Array<Movie>`. I tried this :

`res.body.should.be.an("array");` it works well for the array.

But I don't know how can I test the type inside the array. I tried this:

`res.body.should.be.an("Array<Movie>");`

But it doesn't work I got an error `Uncaught AssertionError: expected [ Array(5014) ] to be an array<movie>`

It is possible to use typescript type to check API response ?

Comment: This question is very similar and has an accepted answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/49047322/2138943

Comment: @PeteTNT Oh yes it's the same question, but the answers not solved my problem. The first show an example with an object by using `instanceof` and the 2nd use a package not updated since 4 years :/. In the chai documentation I seen this https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a we can use custom type maybe there is something possible with that